# simplexml load xml file

Tags: php, simplexml, sql-insert

i have this code to insert in mysql db from a xml file on my server

```
     $xml = simplexml_load_file('/var/www/file.xml');


foreach( $xml->product as $value )
foreach( $xml->product->fields as $categories ) 

{

        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($value->name);
        $number = mysql_real_escape_string($value->sku);
        $description = mysql_real_escape_string($value->description);
        $CategoryPath = mysql_real_escape_string($categories->breadCrumb);



        $sql = "
            INSERT INTO table SET 
                name = '$name',
                sku = '$number',
                description = '$description',
                category = '$CategoryPath'

        ";
        $rssql = mysql_query( $sql );

    }
```

This is the xml structure

```
<product>
<name>Ghost Design 2000 Supporto TV LCD rotation</name>   
<description>
description text...
</description>
<brand>MELICONI</brand>
<sku>8006023191062</sku>
<fields>
<breadCrumb>
Home|Tecnologia e intrattenimento|Tv, DVD, Home Cinema|Accessori Tv/Video|Supporti video
</breadCrumb>
  </fields>
</product>
```

I insert all records in my sql table but the field breadCrumb is not inserted correctly. It insert always the same breadCrumb data for all records.

Comment: Could you provide some more details - e.g. a small section of the XML file so we can see the structure, the inserts you wanted to happen from that XML, and what actually happened.

Comment: Ok.. i edited the post.. thanks @IMSoP

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<products>
<product>
    <name>Ghost Design 2000 Supporto TV LCD rotation</name>   
    <description>description text...</description>
    <brand>MELICONI</brand>
    <sku>8006023191062</sku>
    <fields>
        <breadCrumb>
            Home|Tecnologia e intrattenimento|Tv, DVD, Home Cinema|Accessori Tv/Video|Supporti video
        </breadCrumb>
    </fields>
</product>
<product>
    <name>Ghost Design 2000 Supporto TV LCD rotation</name>   
    <description>
    description text...
    </description>
    <brand>MELICONI</brand>
    <sku>8006023191062</sku>
    <fields>
    <breadCrumb>
    second
    </breadCrumb>
      </fields>
</product>
</products>';
$parsedXml = simplexml_load_string($xml, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);

foreach($parsedXml->product as $product){
    foreach($product->fields as $categories)
        echo $categories->breadCrumb.'<br>';
}
```

That should help you!

Some extra information:

In php 5.5 [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) function is deprecated, use [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<![CDATA[
```

like:

```
<breadCrumb><![CDATA[]]>
Home|Tecnologia e intrattenimento|Tv, DVD, Home Cinema|Accessori Tv/Video|Supporti video 
]]></breadCrumb>
```

Also be sure to use mysql_real_escape_string to put it in database